# Возможно ли получить текст удалённого сообщения?

Tags: python, pyrogram

Хендлер on_deleted_messages возвращает список с объектами {"_": "Message", "id": 6527}. Вопрос: есть ли возможность получить текст удалённого сообщения?

Иначе, единственный вариант, который я могу придумать: сохранять все полученные сообщения в базу, и уже оттуда по айдишнику доставать текст. Но оптимально ли это?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, когда сообщение удаляется пользователем, оно полностью удаляется из чата и серверов Telegram. Так что ваш вариант вполне себе оптимальный. Как альтернатива: можно все сообщения пересылать в свою группу/канал и если оригинал затрут, то у вас он останется.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего нет, так как сообщение удаляется навсегда и безвозвратно, а если сохранять в базу то это будет не очень удобно.

Comment: не стоит давать такие "ответы". оформите его как комментарий к вопросу. а этот ответ удалите.